# Likelihood of an event to belong to a certain cluster in R

Tags: r, clustering

This is a follow up on another question I have while working on this same [dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54927370/labelling-clustered-data/54929815?noredirect=1#comment96656563_54929815) (:`datanet`). Here's a sample of the data:

```
> head(datanet)
   ACTIVITY_X ACTIVITY_Y ACTIVITY_Z   Event
1:         40         47         62 Head-up
2:         60         74         95 Head-up
3:         62         63         88 Head-up
4:         60         56         82 Head-up
5:         66         61         90 Head-up
6:         60         53         80 Head-up
```

Anyways, using the package `dtwclust` I classified and plotted the different `Event`s into different clusters depending on the values of `ACTIVITY_X`, `ACTIVITY_Y` and `ACTIVITY_Z`. Here's how I achieved that:

```
trainset1 <- datanet %>%
  select(-Event)

train <- as.matrix(trainset1, byrow = T, ncol=3)

train_clust <- tsclust(train, k = 4L, type = "fuzzy")

clusters <- tibble(cluster = c(train_clust@cluster))

combined_set <- bind_cols(datanet, clusters)

combined_set %>% 

#Ggplot2 package much better for graphing than the base package
  ggplot(aes(ACTIVITY_X, ACTIVITY_Y, color = as.factor(cluster), shape = Event)) +
  geom_point()
```

In the dataframe `combined_set`, an extra column `"cluster"` relative to the original `datanet` file has been created. It displays the cluster to which each `Event` has been assigned to:

```
> head(combined_set)
   ACTIVITY_X ACTIVITY_Y ACTIVITY_Z   Event cluster
1:         40         47         62 Head-up       4
2:         60         74         95 Head-up       1
3:         62         63         88 Head-up       1
4:         60         56         82 Head-up       1
5:         66         61         90 Head-up       1
6:         60         53         80 Head-up       1
```

However, is there a way to obtain a probability or likelihood value for each `Event` to be associated with a given cluster? It doesn´t necessarily need to be with package `dtwclust`. I'm just wondering if somebody could help me.

Any input is appreciated!

```
> dput(datanet)
structure(list(ACTIVITY_X = c(40L, 60L, 62L, 60L, 66L, 60L, 57L, 
54L, 52L, 93L, 80L, 14L, 52L, 61L, 51L, 40L, 20L, 21L, 5L, 53L, 
48L, 73L, 73L, 21L, 29L, 63L, 59L, 57L, 51L, 53L, 67L, 72L, 74L, 
70L, 60L, 74L, 85L, 77L, 68L, 58L, 80L, 34L, 45L, 34L, 60L, 75L, 
62L, 66L, 51L, 53L, 48L, 62L, 62L, 57L, 5L, 1L, 12L, 23L, 5L, 
4L, 0L, 13L, 45L, 44L, 31L, 68L, 88L, 43L, 70L, 18L, 83L, 71L, 
67L, 75L, 74L, 49L, 90L, 44L, 64L, 57L, 22L, 29L, 52L, 37L, 32L, 
120L, 45L, 22L, 54L, 30L, 9L, 27L, 14L, 3L, 29L, 12L, 10L, 61L, 
60L, 29L, 15L, 7L, 6L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 15L, 23L, 49L, 46L, 8L, 31L, 45L, 60L, 
31L, 37L, 61L, 52L, 51L, 38L, 86L, 60L, 41L, 43L, 40L, 42L, 42L, 
48L, 64L, 71L, 59L, 0L, 11L, 27L, 12L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 21L, 
6L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 46L, 46L, 59L, 53L, 37L, 44L, 39L, 49L, 
37L, 47L, 17L, 36L, 32L, 33L, 26L, 12L, 8L, 25L, 31L, 35L, 27L, 
27L, 24L, 17L, 35L, 39L, 28L, 54L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 17L, 
22L, 25L, 12L, 0L, 5L, 41L, 51L, 66L, 39L, 32L, 53L, 43L, 40L, 
44L, 45L, 48L, 51L, 41L, 45L, 39L, 46L, 59L, 31L, 5L, 24L, 18L, 
5L, 15L, 13L, 0L, 12L, 26L, 0L), ACTIVITY_Y = c(47L, 74L, 63L, 
56L, 61L, 53L, 40L, 41L, 49L, 32L, 54L, 13L, 39L, 99L, 130L, 
38L, 14L, 6L, 5L, 94L, 96L, 38L, 43L, 29L, 47L, 66L, 47L, 38L, 
31L, 36L, 35L, 38L, 72L, 54L, 44L, 45L, 51L, 80L, 48L, 39L, 85L, 
42L, 39L, 37L, 75L, 36L, 45L, 32L, 35L, 41L, 26L, 99L, 163L, 
124L, 0L, 0L, 24L, 37L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 29L, 29L, 26L, 27L, 54L, 
147L, 82L, 98L, 12L, 83L, 97L, 104L, 128L, 81L, 42L, 102L, 60L, 
79L, 58L, 15L, 14L, 75L, 75L, 40L, 130L, 40L, 13L, 54L, 42L, 
7L, 10L, 3L, 0L, 15L, 8L, 7L, 75L, 55L, 26L, 18L, 1L, 13L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 
17L, 45L, 38L, 10L, 31L, 52L, 36L, 24L, 65L, 97L, 45L, 59L, 49L, 
92L, 51L, 34L, 21L, 20L, 29L, 28L, 22L, 32L, 30L, 86L, 0L, 4L, 
15L, 7L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 72L, 
62L, 98L, 55L, 26L, 39L, 28L, 81L, 20L, 52L, 12L, 48L, 24L, 40L, 
30L, 5L, 6L, 44L, 40L, 37L, 33L, 26L, 17L, 14L, 39L, 27L, 28L, 
67L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 7L, 0L, 2L, 39L, 
67L, 74L, 28L, 23L, 57L, 34L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 46L, 43L, 73L, 65L, 
31L, 64L, 128L, 17L, 3L, 12L, 17L, 0L, 9L, 7L, 0L, 7L, 17L, 0L
), ACTIVITY_Z = c(62L, 95L, 88L, 82L, 90L, 80L, 70L, 68L, 71L, 
98L, 97L, 19L, 65L, 116L, 140L, 55L, 24L, 22L, 7L, 108L, 107L, 
82L, 85L, 36L, 55L, 91L, 75L, 69L, 60L, 64L, 76L, 81L, 103L, 
88L, 74L, 87L, 99L, 111L, 83L, 70L, 117L, 54L, 60L, 50L, 96L, 
83L, 77L, 73L, 62L, 67L, 55L, 117L, 174L, 136L, 5L, 1L, 27L, 
44L, 5L, 7L, 0L, 32L, 54L, 51L, 41L, 87L, 171L, 93L, 120L, 22L, 
117L, 120L, 124L, 148L, 110L, 65L, 136L, 74L, 102L, 81L, 27L, 
32L, 91L, 84L, 51L, 177L, 60L, 26L, 76L, 52L, 11L, 29L, 14L, 
3L, 33L, 14L, 12L, 97L, 81L, 39L, 23L, 7L, 14L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 
1L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 16L, 29L, 67L, 
60L, 13L, 44L, 69L, 70L, 39L, 75L, 115L, 69L, 78L, 62L, 126L, 
79L, 53L, 48L, 45L, 51L, 50L, 53L, 72L, 77L, 104L, 0L, 12L, 31L, 
14L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 24L, 7L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 85L, 77L, 
114L, 76L, 45L, 59L, 48L, 95L, 42L, 70L, 21L, 60L, 40L, 52L, 
40L, 13L, 10L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 43L, 37L, 29L, 22L, 52L, 47L, 40L, 
86L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 20L, 25L, 29L, 14L, 0L, 5L, 57L, 
84L, 99L, 48L, 39L, 78L, 55L, 54L, 57L, 58L, 66L, 67L, 84L, 79L, 
50L, 79L, 141L, 35L, 6L, 27L, 25L, 5L, 17L, 15L, 0L, 14L, 31L, 
0L), Event = c("Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", 
"Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Moving", "Moving", 
"Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", 
"Head-up", "Moving", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", 
"Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", 
"Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", 
"Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", 
"Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", 
"Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", 
"Head-up", "Grazing", "Grazing", "Moving", "Moving", "Grazing", 
"Grazing", "Grazing", "Moving", "Moving", "Grazing", "Grazing", 
"Grazing", "Grazing", "Grooming", "Grooming", "Grazing", "Grazing", 
"Grooming", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Vigilance", "Grazing", "Grazing", 
"Grazing", "Grazing", "Vigilance", "Grazing", "Grazing", "Grazing", 
"Grazing", "Moving", "Grazing", "Grazing", "Grazing", "Grazing", 
"Grazing", "Moving", "Vigilance", "Vigilance", "Vigilance", "Head-up", 
"Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Grazing", "Grazing", "Grazing", 
"Grazing", "Grazing", "Grazing", "Grazing", "Grazing", "Grazing", 
"Grazing", "Grazing", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", 
"Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", 
"Head-up", "Grazing", "Grazing", "Grazing", "Grazing", "Grazing", 
"Grooming", "Grazing", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", 
"Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", 
"Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Moving", "Moving", "Vigilance", 
"Vigilance", "Grazing", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", 
"Head-up", "Moving", "Grazing", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", 
"Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", 
"Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", 
"Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", 
"Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Grazing", 
"Grazing", "Grazing", "Grazing", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Grazing", 
"Head-up", "Vigilance", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Moving", 
"Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", 
"Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", 
"Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", 
"Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", 
"Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", 
"Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", "Head-up", 
"Vigilance")), row.names = c(NA, -228L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000051e1ef0>)
```

Comment: What exactly is the model from which you want to calculate probability? Or what exactly is your definition of probability in this case? This doesn't really sound like a programming question, it sounds like you need recommendations for modeling your data from the statisticians over at [stats.se].

Comment: I'm not sure "probability" or "likelihood" are the terms you are looking for. If you used fuzzy clustering, you can indeed see each row's degree of "belongingness" in the **f**cluster slot.

Comment: @Alexis thank you for your answer and sorry for my late reply. I was wondering how I can access the fcluster slot for each row as you mention in your comment?

Comment: `train_clust@fcluster`